# Use iPhone as display for computer?

Tags: iphone, display

Is there a way to use an iPhone as an external monitor for a computer?

I'm particularly interested in the potential of using an iPhone with [Google Cardboard](https://store.google.com/product/google_cardboard) as a VR device.  But instead of using it just with iPhone apps, I'd like to be able to use it with programs that run on my computer.

I've never seen anything that allows an iPhone to be an external display, but that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jules, I suggest making that an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you want to use a device such as an iPhone as an extra display for your desktop computer. If so, you will need to use 3rd party software to do this, such as [Duet Display](http://www.duetdisplay.com/).

I have used this app to set an iPad up as an external monitor for an iMac and it works well for some workflows. How well it works for you will depend on what you're trying to do and the hardware you're using.

In any case, I know that [Duet Display](http://www.duetdisplay.com/) works with both iPads and iPhones and works with both Mac and Windows. However, I can not share any personal experience in using with an iPhone or Windows.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a viable option, if you would consider mirroring instead of extending:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-2-remote-desktop/id561386772

"Use Splashtop to access your computer on the local network with best-in-class video streaming performance."

It's basically remote desktop but they boast high performance.